# How to render component from string in litelement

Tags: lit-element, lit

How to render component from string in litelement? It is possible or it is possible to convert string to TemplateResult?

My code not working

```
export class MyElement extends ScopedElementsMixin(LitElement) {
    static get scopedElements() {
        return {
          'panel-group': PanelGroup,
          'panel': Panel,
        }
      }

    static get properties() { 
        return {
            controls: { type: String }
        }
    }

    createRenderRoot() {
        return this;
    }
    
    render() {
        // example insert string
        // const controls = "<panel-group name=panel><panel key=0 panelValue=0 label=true></panel><panel key=1 panelValue=1 label=false></panel></panel-group>"

        return html`${unsafeHTML`${this.props.controls}`}`; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`unsafeHTML` is a directive. You can use as below code.

```
render() {
    // example insert string
    // const controls = "<panel-group name=panel><panel key=0 panelValue=0 label=true></panel><panel key=1 panelValue=1 label=false></panel></panel-group>"

    return html`${unsafeHTML(this.props.controls)}`; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     render() {
    //example insert string
     const controls = "<panel-group name=panel><panel key=0 panelValue=0 label=true></panel><panel key=1 panelValue=1 label=false></panel></panel-group>"
     const component= html([controls]);
     return component; 
     }
```

Comment: Note that this approach requires that the custom element referenced in the component string has already been defined and registered with the customElements registry

Answer (score 0):

is the point to render something from an HTML string or specifically to use lit in order to do this? could use `updated` to respond to `controls` being updated and do something like

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = this.controls;
this.querySelector('.targetToPlaceThis').innerHTML = div.innerHTML; // (or some kind of append loop)
```